socket.io client shows connected as true, but still does not send any events
I am using react with socket.io to facilitate websocket communication between client and server. Below is the code I am using.
const Main = () => {
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState();
  const [socketConnected, setSocketConnected] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
     const baseUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_URL;
     const s = io(baseUrl, {
       withCredentials: true,
     });
     s.on("connect", () => {
       console.log("socket connected");
       setSocketConnected(s.connected);
     });
     setSocket(s);
     return () => {
       s.disconnect();
     };
   }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
     if (!socket || !socketConnected) return;
      socket.emit("join", {data});
      console.log("emitted join-room event");
      console.log(socket.connected);
      socket.emit("join-room", {
        data
      });
      console.log(socket.connected);
    }

  }, [socket, socketConnected])
}

This events are not being sent to the server even though I can see that the socket.connected is true
If I try to establish a socket connection on the previous page, that is the page before the page where Main component is being rendered, and after that if I send events from the Main component, everything works fine. The events are sent to the server

Ok, I am specifying what worked for me.
Once the client receives 'connect' event from server, I listen for 'ready' event from the server, which the server emits on succesful connection. Code below :-
// client code
s.on("connect", () => {
  console.log("socket connected");
  s.on('ready', () => {
    setSocketConnected(s.connected);   
  })
});

// server code
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.emit("ready");
}

